# Slow git clone speed, everything else +12Mbit/s

Tags: ubuntu, git, connection, cable-modem

I'm trying to do a git clone, using ubuntu 16.04 server edition (don't ask, I needed a quick ubuntu for an openwrt build) and, while fast.com, xfinity's speedtest and speedtest.net both show 12Mbit/s download and 2Mbit/s upload, git download speed is slow as heck.

Is there any way to speed this up? the commands I'm running are:

```
dragon@ubuntu:~$ git clone --depth=1 git://git.openwrt.org/openwrt.git openwrt
Cloning into 'openwrt'...
remote: Counting objects: 8412, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7202/7202), done.
Receiving objects:  50% (4232/8412), 4.54 MiB | 10.00 KiB/s
```

Notice the **10.00 KiB/s** (and it's been lower down to 1024 Bytes/s!). What could be wrong?. I'm connected directly to the modem, it's been factory reset, everything goes smooth except this!

uname -a:

```
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is restriction on openwrt.org to prevent server abuse on their side

Comment: Right, I missed the URL was pointing to openwrt.org instead of github.com, still if any of the openwrt.org admins read this, downloading at a max of 10Kib/s is totally unbearable, I understand the abuse and all, but the speed is just depressing :( I spent like 30 minutes or more downloading it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why are you using openwrt.org, when on the [GetSource](https://dev.openwrt.org/wiki/GetSource) page they say the repos moved to [github](https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt)? I guess they keep openwrt.org git as a backup. Move on...

Comment: I was actually using an old tutorial it seems, which had that URL instead of github. They should've turned it off instead of leaving it there and confusing users this way :(